# Storing and plotting spline fit from cox.zph

Tags: r, plot, survival-analysis, cox-regression, r-mice

I have 50 multiply imputed datasets created by mice, and I am running a Cox model on each of them. I need to verify the assumption of proportional hazards over time, and to do so I will check out the plots from cox.zph.

What I would like to do is plot the splines that come from each dataset on the same plot. I know that this would normally be done with `lines()` after a call to `plot`, but when I do this with my zph object, R connects every point, which obviously isn't what I want.

I tried to plot once, and then plot over it in a loop. Individual zph is just a list of all of my cox analyses

```
plot(individual_zph[[1]][1],resid=FALSE,ylim=c(-1.5,1),se=FALSE)

for(i in 2:50){
par(new=TRUE)
plot(individual_zph[[i]][1],resid=FALSE,ylim=c(-1.5,1),se=FALSE) 
}
```

And this will put it all on one plot, but it is blurry/bold because the same thing has been plotted so many times.

[image: plot]

Is there a better way to do this, or is this plot the best that I can get?

Comment: I've got a github-installable package - https://github.com/hrbrmstr/gghazard that will let you "fortify" the data from the analysis and use ggplot2. if the pkg isn't explanatory enough, post a bit of real data and i can show an example here.

Answer (score 0):

add a bit of alpha in your plots. You dont present a reproducible example so I had to come up with my own. The plots look better in non windows enviroments

```
a=0.3
b=1.6
g=0.8

curve(5+(a*x)+(b*(x^2))-(g*(x^3)), from=-100, to=100, col=rgb(0, 0, 139,alpha = 40, maxColorValue = 255 ))


for (i in 1:200){

a=runif(n = 1, min=0.1, max=0.8)
b=runif(n = 1, min=1, max=2.5)
g=runif(n = 1, min=0.65, max=1.4)

curve(5+(a*x)+(b*(x^2))-(g*(x^3)), from=-100, to=100, add = T, col=rgb(0, 0, 139,alpha = 40 , maxColorValue = 255))
}
```